# Trim string in c# output last string

Tags: c#

I'm currently making a Game and I have already split the string everything right but how I can trim the string and output the last line or a line in the middle?

Code:

```
text = "Username:King100 ID:100 Level:10";
string[] splittext = text.Split(' ');
foreach (var texs in splittext)
{
    Console.WriteLine(texs);
}
```

Output:

```
Username:King100  
ID:100  
Level:10
```

I just want display the level `10` in the Console how thats works?
thanxs for helping.

Edit: the level can be changed often like 10 or 100 or 1000

Comment: split the text again and try to find the line with token[0] == "Level" and output token[1]. Or learn how to use regex to do a one liner

Comment: Is level always the last part of the string?

Comment: ill give you a +1 for filling up 20 minutes of my time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is more flexible solution. But if your text format is contsant, you can use this simple way:

```
string level = text.Substring(text.LastIndexOf(':') + 1);
```

Comment: Hey, that works very good and is very easy thanxs, but my output goes to another line like   
`Your level is  
10` but 10 is in a new line how I can fix that?

Comment: if the actual level number is always in the last line, just replace ':' with '\n' in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a Regular Expression to solve this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"Level:(?<Level>\d*)");
var matches = regex.Matches("Username:King100 ID:100 Level:10");

if (matches.Count > 0 && matches[0].Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Groups["Level"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = "Username:King100 ID:100 Level:10";

/* 
   Splits the given string on spaces and then splits on ":"
   and creates a Dictionary ("Dictionary<TKey, TValue>")
*/
var dict = text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
               .Select(part => part.Split(':'))
               .ToDictionary(split => split[0], split => split[1]);

//If the dictionary count is greater than Zero
if(dict.Count > 0)
{
  var levelValue = dict["Level"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: I routinely downvote "code-only" answers because I believe they are not particularly useful: The person seeking an answer can copy the code, but will not necessarily understand what it does. This encourages SODD: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361904/what-is-stack-overflow-driven-development If you could add an explanation to your answer (needn't be long, a sentence or two or a couple of comments), I would be happy to turn my downvote into an upvote.

Comment: Added the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If level is always the last part of the string, and all you care about is the actual number, then you can just do:

```
var level = text.Split(':').LastOrDefault();
```

This would just split on `':'` and give you the last (or default) element. Given your example input, `level = "10"`.

Answer (score 0):

OK, because i'm annoying and totally bored of work, i decided to benchmark everyone's solutions.

The premise was simply to make an array of 1000 (scale) lines of strings (in the given format) with random positive `int` on the end;

> **Note** : I made every solution `int.Parse` the result, as it seemed more useful

**Mine**

This just uses `fixed`, `unsafe`, pointers and no error checking

```
var level = 0;
fixed (char* pitem = item)
{
   var len = pitem + item.Length;

   for (var p = pitem ; p < len; p++)
      if (*p >= '0' && *p <= '9')
         level = level * 10 + *p - 48;
      else
         level = 0;                 
}
```

**Results**

```
Mode            : Release
Test Framework  : .NET Framework 4.7.1
Benchmarks runs : 1000 times (averaged)

Scale : 1,000
Name       |   Average |   Fastest | StDv |     Cycles | Pass |      Gain
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Mine       |  0.095 ms |  0.085 ms | 0.01 |    317,205 | Yes  |   96.59 %
Sanan      |  0.202 ms |  0.184 ms | 0.02 |    680,747 | Yes  |   92.75 %
Zaza       |  0.373 ms |  0.316 ms | 0.10 |  1,254,302 | Yes  |   86.60 %
Kishore    |  0.479 ms |  0.423 ms | 0.06 |  1,620,756 | Yes  |   82.81 %
Hussein    |  1.045 ms |  0.946 ms | 0.11 |  3,547,305 | Yes  |   62.50 %
Maccettura |  2.787 ms |  2.476 ms | 0.39 |  9,474,133 | Base |    0.00 %
Hardkoded  |  6.691 ms |  5.927 ms | 0.67 | 22,750,311 | Yes  | -140.09 %
Tom        | 11.561 ms | 10.635 ms | 0.78 | 39,344,419 | Yes  | -314.80 %
```

## Summary

- All the solutions do different things in different ways, comparing them is not really apples to apples.
- **Don't use mine**, its totally unrealistic and only for fun. Use the version that makes the most sense to you, that is the most robust and easiest to maintain.
- As always, regex is the slowest.

Comment: `level = level * 10 + *p - '0';` would be more intuitive. at least)

Comment: @SananFataliyev how this is a late reply, and you are absolutely correct :)

Comment: its late because I've been staring at your code and trying to understand what's going on for six months :)

Comment: @SananFataliyev yeah i must have been bored that day, its a totally nonsensical solution

Answer (score -1):

```
string text = texs.Substring(texs.IndexOf("Level:")+6);
System.Console.WriteLine(text);
```

Comment: substring takes two arguments. Also, this is pretty much just the answer I gave. `text.IndexOf("Level:")+6` will go out of range as a start index

Comment: @emsimpson92 i've tested the code on .net core and it works fine, using the following overload: string.Substring(int StartIndex)

Comment: I misread that. For whatever reason I was thinking IndexOf() returned the index directly after the specified string, not the index where it begins.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
string input = "Username:King100 ID:100 Level:10";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"\s*Level:(?<level>\d+)");
if (m.Success&& m.Groups["level"].Success)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["level"].Value);
```

Also works for:

```
string input = "Username:King100 Level:10 ID:100";
```